# how to set switch for ON and OFF iphone sound in setting page

Tags: iphone, audio

I have setting page in this page Uiswitch as sound toggle button for ON and OFF. Implemeted UIswitch with on and off control and working fine with out audio. Now i need control iPhone sound through UISwitch  for ON and OFF , Same how to set default setting .any one provide me some tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

there is no way to switch on/off sound global iPhone sound without using private API