# swith on/off sound on iphone ( phoneGap + construct 2 )

Tags: ios, audio, cordova

i have done a game using construct 2, this game is called in an iframe in a JqueryMobile page.
my problem is that sometime when i click 'back button' some sound still played ( sounds are not a background sound but FX and are in queu so i cant stop theme with construct 2 pause function ).
my solution is to set sound off on iphone, but according this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624874/how-to-set-switch-for-on-and-off-iphone-sound-in-setting-page?rq=1), i have to use private api and that mean a rejected app.

have you a solution for this ?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Construct 2 automatically pauses audio when the app is 'suspended' (in an invisible tab in a browser, or moved to the background as a mobile app).  However I guess an iframe in a PhoneGap app doesn't fire the right events.

You can call them yourself, though: call these functions in the iframe to pause and resume the entire game (which includes audio):

```
cr_setSuspended(true);  // pause game and mute audio
cr_setSuspended(false); // resume game and unmute audio
```